# Django: Admin action choices

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been searching up and down to look for an answer but sadly, no.

I am trying to add actions in the django admin dropdown(where `Delete Selected` is) but after adding some actions, the actions I have added also shows on the other models, I have followed the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) but no luck

How do I restrict the actions I have added to a certain model only?

Thanks in advance.

(I am using python 2.7, django 1.8.2)

**EDIT**

I am filtering the choices by user type(superuser or not) via:

```
#This a test application only

def fire_employee(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(APP_STATUS=8)
fire_employee.short_description = "Fire/Retire Employee"

class hrd(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = hired_applicant
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(hrd, self).get_actions(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if 'delete_selected' in actions:
                del actions['delete_selected']
        else:
            self.actions.append(fire_employee)
        return actions
    list_display = ('FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'EMAIL', 'APPLICATION_DATE', 'APP_STATUS')

admin.site.register(hired_applicant, hrd)
```

Comment: Can you expand the code above to show the rest of the `AdminModel` class

Comment: Edited, is it also possible to use  `queryset.save()` instead of `.update()` in `fire_employee`?

Comment: You could loop the query set calling .save() against every model `for obj in queryset: obj.APP_STATUS = 8; obj.save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the `AdminModel` class this I'm still not sure if you were using the same class for all the models.

```
@admin.site.register(ModelOne, ModelTwo)
class AdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(AdminModel, self).get_actions(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if 'delete_selected' in actions:
                del actions['delete_selected']
        else:
            self.actions.append(make_published)
            self.actions.append(make_unpublished)
        return actions
```

If you want only the actions for specific models you'd just make two separate `ModelAdmin` classes

```
@admin.site.register(ModelOne)
class AdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(AdminModel, self).get_actions(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            if 'delete_selected' in actions:
                del actions['delete_selected']
        else:
            self.actions.append(make_published)
            self.actions.append(make_unpublished)
        return actions


@admin.site.register(ModelTwo)
class NoActionsModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Additionally on the `ModelAdmin` you should be able to prevent all but superusers by using the `has_delete_permission` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission)) function

```
class AdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.is_superuser
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did, the problem starts when I access the other models in the admin the choices still remains

Comment: do you have multiple `admin.site.register` calls? `admin.site.register(hired_applicant, hrd)` ... `admin.site.register(other_model, hrd)`

Comment: I found what was wrong in my code, I need to declare `actions = []` in the `ModelAdmin` because without it, it adds the action to all models